ipywidgets - how to avoid flicker in text Output
I'm trying to create a viewer for a time-series of text data (i.e., a user typing) using ipywidgets.
I have something like the following:
code_out = widgets.Output()
# continuous_update=True is ideal for my use case
code_index_slider = widgets.IntSlider(continuous_update=True)

def update_out():
    code_out.clear_output()
    code_out.append_stdout("New data...")

def change_code_index(change):
    if change.name == "value" and change.new != change.old:
        update_out()

code_index_slider.observe(change_code_index)
display(code_index_slider)
display(code_out)


It works as expected, excepts there's a huge flicker between the output clear and the new data being added.
I've seen suggestions on how to solve this for matplotlib specifically, essentially modify rather than clear the output, but I'm not sure how to do this for text data. Essentially, I just want to hold the UI update until I'm done modifying output.
I've tried using wait=True in clear_output, but that seems to allow for many appendss to occur before the output is cleared. Maybe I'm doing that wrong...
Related: if I try
with code_out:
    code_out.clear_output(wait=True)
    print("New data...")

it seems to reduce the flicker, but then I get everything printed 3 times... I'm in VS Code - not sure if that could have something to do with it.
Thanks!
